# C# Send object to webservice with SOAP

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, httpwebrequest

I have a class :

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="MyClass", Namespace="http://model.common.party.ent.gfdi.be")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class MyClass : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged 
{

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string firstname;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string lastname;
}
```

I create an instance :

```
   var myClass = new MyClass() { lastname = "AAA", firstname = "BBB" };
```

I'd like send this instance to the webservice.

I'd like send this object to a web service. The message received by the web service should look this :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:membership="http://service.common.party.ent.gfdi.be 
http://service.common.party.ent.gfdi.be">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <membership:find>
         <membership:in0>
           <membership:lastname>AAA</membership:lastname>
           <membership:firstname>BBB</membership:firstname>
         </membership:in0>
      </membership:find>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried this :

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myurl);
webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX=";
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
webRequest.Method = "POST";

XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

string soapResult;
using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
{
    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
    }
    Console.Write(soapResult);
}

private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
    }
}

private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
{
    XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
    soapEnvelop.LoadXml(@"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema""><SOAP-ENV:Body><HelloWorld xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/""><int1 xsi:type=""xsd:integer"">12</int1><int2 xsi:type=""xsd:integer"">32</int2></HelloWorld></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");
    return soapEnvelop;
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: Does this service have wsdl description?

Comment: How about actually trying to send the message you want to send instead of some kind of Hello World example you currently have in your code?

Comment: @CarlosLanderas Yes. The "problem" is when I copy/paste the URL in the browser, a login/password (via an HTML page) is asked before access the WSDL and I don't know how solve the problem (I tried with Credential but not work)

Comment: Do you know the password? In case you are, manually download the definition and run the [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) on the saved file.

Comment: Of course, I know the password.

Comment: So have you tried the svcutil approach?

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comments I would do the following:

- I would request the user/password of the web service url and authenticate with internet explorer (outside visual studio).
- Then in project , use the add service reference--> advanced --> add webreference. option and introduce the URL it should not request authentication since IExplorer is already authenticated.
- If you manage to get the WSDL service description parse and create the WS Classes, then you are done because you can provide the basic authentication to the webService once you want to consume the webservice using:

  ```
  WebServiceClass wsClass = new WebServiceClass();
  wsClass .Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
  ```